# JAXB don't want to use interface

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb

I'm working on eclipse with JBoss 6.0.2.
I exposed some EJBs as web service with success.

But at the last Ejb wich i want to expose,when i deploy my appication on JBoss, i got this error :

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriterium is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriterium
                at private java.util.ArrayList com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriteria.criteria
                at com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriteria
                at private java.util.ArrayList com.upsilon.beans.client.jaxws_asm.GetPortfolios.arg2
                at com.upsilon.beans.client.jaxws_asm.GetPortfolios
com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriterium does not have a no-arg default constructor.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriterium
                at private java.util.ArrayList com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriteria.criteria
                at com.upsilon.beans.pfselection.SelectionCriteria
                at private java.util.ArrayList com.upsilon.beans.client.jaxws_asm.GetPortfolios.arg2
                at com.upsilon.beans.client.jaxws_asm.GetPortfolios

        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Here is my interface :

```
public interface SelectionCriterium //extends Serializable
{

}
```

here is my class SelectionCriteria

```
public class SelectionCriteria //implements Serializable
{


    private ArrayList<SelectionCriterium> criteria = new ArrayList<SelectionCriterium>( );

public SelectionCriteria(){}

public SelectionCriteria( ArrayList<SelectionCriterium> criteria )
{
    this.criteria = criteria;
}

/*public SelectionCriteria( )
{
    criteria = new ArrayList<SelectionCriterium>( );
}*/


public ArrayList<SelectionCriterium> getCriteria( )
{
    return criteria;
}

public void setCriteria( ArrayList<SelectionCriterium> criteria )
{
    this.criteria = criteria;
}

public void addCriterium( SelectionCriterium criterium )
    {
        criteria.add( criterium );
    }
}
```

I tried to put Xml annotations but it doesn't works :/

If someone have an idea ? Thanks a lot (sorry for my english)

Comment: JAXB is used to handle XML/JSON to/from POJO marshalling/unmarshalling, so it is quite obvious that you have to provide an interface implementation to JAXB (with no argument constructor) to do the stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a mapped field/property that is an interface type you need to use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the implementation type.

```
@XmlElement(type=SelectionCriteriumImpl.class)
public ArrayList<SelectionCriterium> getCriteria( )
{
    return criteria;
}
```

**Additional Information**

You can find more information about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works.
In fact my interface is empty,then i just create a SelectionCriteriumImpl implements SelectionCriterium.
And i added the annotation. 
My project is deployed and also my web service :)
Thanks a lot !